# Equation for regions inside the triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, geometry

Let $a,b,c$ be distinct point in $\mathbb{C}$.

[image]

Then, what would be an algebraic equation that designates this region inside the triangle including the boundary?

For example, $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: Re(z)^2 + Im(z)^2 \leq 1\}$ is an equation for a closed ball.

Likewise, what would it be for this case?

Is it $\{b+ t(c-b) + s(a-c): t,s\in [0,1]\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to describe this is as a *convex combination* of $a,b,c$:

$$T = \{\lambda_1a + \lambda_2b + \lambda_3c : \lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3 = 1, \  \lambda_i \geq 0\}$$

This is basically a weighted average, where the weights are non-negative.

Comment: @Rubertos You're welcome! By the way, your own attempt was close, but doesn't quite work. To see this at a glance, note that your parameters $s$ and $t$ are independent of each other, so you won't get a triangle but instead a quadrilateral.